# nginx rewrite rule exclude numbers

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

Need some help with Nginx write rule such that:

All urls of type:-

```
/1.1.1/xyz/abc/z.js
/2.2.2/xyz/def/c.css
```

are re-directed to

```
/xyz/abc/z.js
/xyz/def/c.css
```

Want to exclude the numeric part which comes at the beginning of URL.

Comment: Something like this? http://serverfault.com/a/302512

Comment: Yes, similar to the question above. I used the following:

rewrite ^/(d+)\.(d+)\.(d+)(.*)$ $1 last;

but it does not work.

Comment: Turn on debug level error logging. All of the solutions given should work, so something else is going on. Do you also realize that when using rewrites the url in the browser does not change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
location ~ ^/[0-9\.]+(/.*) {
    try_files $1 $1/;
}
```

Comment: A single segment like 1.3.4 or 5.6.7.
Above rule did not help.

Comment: do you want a redirect or a rewrite ? , and please also verify that you reload nginx settings after changing.

Comment: I want a rewrite. And yes I restart the nginx service after change.

Comment: try the edited answer, do you want to force it to match only when starting with 3 numbers? the above rule should match any number of numbers and dots.

Answer (score 0):

this will work

rewrite ^/(d+).(d+).(d+)/(.+)$ /$1;